# Multiple background threads

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have one c# application that uses BackGroundWorker to do a group of tasks:

```
 private void buttonStartCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                BackgroundWorker checkOuter = new BackgroundWorker();
                checkOuter.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(checkOuter_DoWork);
                checkOuter.RunWorkerAsync();
                checkOuter.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(checkOuter_RunWorkerCompleted);
            }

        void checkOuter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBoxCICheckOut.Text != "")
                CheckOutCI();

            if (textBoxCACheckOut.Text != "")
                CheckOutCA();

            if (textBoxCAuthCheckOut.Text != "")
                CheckOutCAuth();

            if (textBoxCLCheckOut.Text != "")
                CheckOutCL();

            if (textBoxCCCheckOut.Text != "")
                CheckOutCC();
        }
```

As you can see, I have only 2 threads; one for GUI and one for secondary task.
Its easy for me to track when all the functions finish.
Now I want to make it more fast by creating a separate thread for CheckOutCI(), CheckOutCA() and others.Creating 5 background workers looks kinda dirty.

I want to ask:
How will I keep track of when all the functions have finished executing.

If any one function returned an exception, I want to display it to user and ask the user to correct the user and try again.  I hope I am able to explain my question properly.
**PLEASE edit the code by wdavo as per my comment on his post.**

Comment: Sounds like you might get yourself into a few convoluted problems. You could use 5 background workers, but managing which finished and failed could be difficult. You could try and look into [System.Reactive](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/system.reactive/info) for this.

Comment: You have cross threading issues.  The background worker is NOT on the UI thread and can NOT access a UI Control (such as textBoxCCCheckOut).

Comment: @RichardSchneider Yes, I know that and I am properly dispatching them to the UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

I'd look at using the Task library (Assuming you are running .NET 4.5 or later). I find it much better to use than background workers in most cases.

(Note you can still use the Task library in .NET 4, however Task.WhenAll is only available in 4.5)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235618

Without rewriting your whole program, here's an example of how you would use it:

Move your simple conditional logic to the button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();

  if (Text == "A")
  {
    tasks.Add(funcA());
  }

  if (Text == "B")
  {
    tasks.Add(funcB());
  }

  //And so on....

  Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    if (t.Exception != null)
    {
      //One of the tasks threw an exception
      MessageBox.Show("There was an exception!");
    }
    else
    {
      //None of the tasks threw an exception
      MessageBox.Show("No Exceptions!");
    }
  });

}
```

We add the tasks to a collection so we can know when they all finish via Task.WhenAll. When all the tasks in the collection have finished, a message box will be displayed. If any of the tasks in the collection have thrown an exception, the Exception property of 't' will be populated. The specific exceptions exist as inner exceptions of this exception.

Move your threading code to individual task/functions. You'd create your checkout functions to look similar to this:

```
private Task funcA()
{
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    try
    {
      //Code running here will be executed on another thread
      //This is where you would put your time consuming work
      //
      //
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //Handle any exception locally if needed
      //If you do handle it locally, make sure you throw it again so we can see it in Task.WhenAll
      throw ex;
    }

    //Do any required UI updates after the work
    //We aren't on the UI thread, so you will need to use BeginInvoke
    //'this' would be a reference to your form
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
      //...
    }));

  });
}
```

What this does is the following

- Creates a and runs a task which does some work on a thread from the thread pool
- If there is an exception, we handle it locally .We re-throw the exception so that we can know that a task has failed when 'Task.WhenAll' is executed
- Updates the UI after the work is done. You need to call BeginInvoke to run the code on the UI thread to avoid cross threading issues.

Comment: Very good, concise explanation. I use this approach myself when I need more than one background operation at once.

Comment: @davo: How will I abort the other tasks once any task throws an exception and how will I check if all the tasks completed without exception ? Should I declare some bool variables which individual tasks would set to true on completion and then in Task.WhenAll check all the bools ?

Comment: That would work but it's not really a good practice. The tasks in your tasks collection have an exception property you can check to see if a task has caused an exception. I would say if you _need_ to cancel a task if another fails, then there is something fundamentally wrong with what you are trying to do (you can't know where the task is up to when you try to cancel it, so you might be trying to cancel it when it's already finished). Exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614 Cancelling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607

Comment: (Cancelling a task is fine if its to avoid waiting for it)

Comment: So the exceptions in the Task are handled automatically and I should check Iterate through the tasks to see if any exception occured ? Will the exception be null in case there is no exception at all ?

Comment: Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show("All done");
  }); It has syntax errors, along with some other errors.

Comment: I've added an example of how you might handle exceptions. If you're next question is going to be about cancellation I'd recommend reading the msdn stuff on it and googling around. If you're still stuck after that it's probably worth a new post.

Comment: There is nothing like Task.WhenAll() :(

Comment: What .net version are you targeting? Task.WhenAll is 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Starting up more threads than CPUs or cores can actually make your application slower.  When there are more CPU-bound threads than CPUs the OS needs to context switch more often between the threads--which is hugely expensive and could result in the OS spending more time context switching between your threads than giving them time to work.

You can use the parallel aspect of the Parallel Task Library to automatically distribute your load across CPUs.   For example:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[] {CheckOutCI, CheckOutCA, CheckOutCAuth, CheckOutCL, CheckOutCC};
Parallel.ForEach(actions, e=>e());
```

...which isn't exactly what you want; but should give you a general idea.  e.g. populate `actions` based on current conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ReportProgress method in backgroundworker

```
void checkOuter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxCICheckOut.Text != "")
            CheckOutCI();
            checkOuter.ReportProgress(completionPercentage,"Error message");
```

The data sent in ReportProgress can be captured in checkOuter_ProgressChanged event

```
 checkOuter_ProgressChanged(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     int percentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
     string message = e.UserState;
 }
```

Comment: This won't help tracking the end of the operations, that's the job of the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler (unless you "cheat" and arbitrarily treat a specific `ProgressPercentage` as the "I'm done!" signal, which I would avoid).